# Select box fade in fade out feature?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, css

I am trying to create a select tag. In my select tag when user will click on Actions, It will open option but slowly same feature like fade in fade out.
I tried to implement jQuery but didn't get any.

My code:

```
<select ng-model="feederActions" ng-options="action.name for action in actions">
      <option value="" disabled>Actions</option>
</select>
```

It will render as:

```
<select ng-model="feederActions" ng-options="action.name for action in actions" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <option value="" disabled="" class="">Actions</option>
    <option value="0">Ping</option>
    <option value="1">On Demand Read</option>
    <option value="2">Theft Status</option>
</select>
```

This is angular code.

On click of Actions I want to achieve this:

[image: picture]

Can I achieve this using normal select tag Html5?

Comment: Do you want to fade-in/out a normal select tag without any JS code?

Comment: I tried with js code it is not working... so I thought to use using CSS

Comment: If we can do it with jquery/JS its fine.. But I am now geeting how to do it..

Comment: But the normal select is rendered by the browser (and the operating system, based on the options set by the user, for example Windows theme) and you don't have a way to manipulate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more customizable select input, try to use [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).